# Returning one result set from a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am starting to try to get familiar with stored procedures in MySQL.

I wonder if it is possible to construct a result set step by step - or am I required to use a temporary table?

My first shot was

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (id int);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (id1 int, id2 int);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (5,4),(3,2),(1,0),(12,34);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS curdemo;

delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE a INT;
  DECLARE b,c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM t1 LIMIT 1000;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT id1, id2 FROM t2 LIMIT 1000;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;
  -- 1
  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;
    FETCH cur2 INTO b, c;
    IF NOT done THEN
       SELECT a, b, c;
       -- 2
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
  -- 3
END

//

DELIMITER ;
```

This leads to 4 result sets each containing one row. What I want is one result set containing 4 rows.

So I added

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tt;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt (id1 int, id2 int, id3 int);

INSERT INTO tt VALUES (a, b, c);

SELECT * FROM tt;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tt;
```

at the appropriate places (--1, --2 - with replacing the SELECT, and --3), and it worked.

My question now: Is there another way to do so? Maybe declare the form of my result set once and then "yield" row by row, without having the need for the temporary table (and its temporary storage allocation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just combine the two selects using a join like so:

```
SELECT id, id1, id2 FROM (
  SELECT @rank:= @rank+1 as rank1, t1.id, t2.id1, t2.id2 FROM t1 
  STRAIGHT JOIN (SELECT @rank:= 1) r
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT @rank as rank2, id1, id2 FROM t2 LIMIT 1000) s
    ON (rank1 = rank2)
  ) s1
```

Comment: Thx 4 ya answer. It would be feasible in this example case, but not in the general case. (in which one could, however, think about other possibilities). But there seems really no other way to do it...